# Construction a formal system ⊢X ¬φ iff ⊢H φ

Tags: logic

Doing some exercises from the textbook, and stumbled upon this question with absolutely no idea how to go about solving it.
We want to construct a new formal system X that is the perfect liar of propositional
logic, meaning that for every formula φ we have:

```
⊢X ¬φ iff ⊢H φ
```

In other words, theorems in X are exactly the negations of theorems in H. Formulate axioms and
deduction rule(s) that define such a system X .

Does anyone have an example of such a system?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Math.SE!

> Does anyone have an example of such a system?

Since your main question is about an example, I will give you one, along with a brief description on why the example has the required property. In the end, I'll briefly discuss how you could come up with other examples.

Gentzen's [sequent calculus **LK**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#The_system_LK) has left rules, which can be applied only to formulas on the left of the turnstile $\vdash_{LK}$, and right rules, which can be applied only to formulas to the right of the turnstile.

Moreover, the right rule for negation allows us to take a formula from the right of the turnstile to the left of the turnstile (and vice versa for the left rule):

$$\frac{\Gamma, A \vdash_{LK} \Delta }{\Gamma\vdash_{LK}\Delta, \neg A} \neg\text{right}$$

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash_{LK} \Delta, A }{\Gamma, \neg A\vdash_{LK}\Delta} \neg\text{left}$$

It follows easily that $\vdash_{LK} \neg \varphi$ precisely if $\varphi \vdash_{LK}$. We can use this property to construct a "lying" counterpart **LKH** to **LK**: simply take the sequent system in which left rules can be applied only to formulas on the *right* of the turnstile $\vdash_{LKH}$, while right rules can only be applied on the *left* of the turnstile $\vdash_{LKH}$. More precisely, **LKH** has the left rules of **LK** as its right rules, and it has the right rules of **LK** as its left rules.

This means that $\vdash_{LKH} \varphi$ precisely if $\varphi \vdash_{LK}$ precisely if $\vdash_{LK} \neg \varphi$, as desired.

> How could you come up with your own system?

Well, you could exploit [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Every other propositional operation can be defined in terms of $\wedge, \vee, \neg$, and negation allows you to switch between $\wedge$ and $\vee$. So if you start with a proof system that has rules for $\wedge, \vee, \neg$, you can usually "dualize" these rules using De Morgan's laws to create your liar system. Indeed, this is what happens with **LK** above: the left rules for $\wedge$ happen to be the same as the right rules for $\vee$.